# Insercion en bucle a base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, foreach

Quiero subir cada uno de los: Titulos, Listas y descripciones
Sabiendo que:
$titulo se ejecuta 40 veces con titulos diferentes
$lista se ejecuta 40 veces con lista diferentes
$descripcion se ejecuta 40 veces con descripcion diferentes
No logro conseguir que se suban los (3) elementos al mismo tiempo a la base de datos al recorrer el foreach.
Debo decir que borré codigo aqui por que tengo más codigo y más datos, queria hacer lo mas simple posible.
Hay alguna manera de hacerlo, si algo esta errrado editare mi pregunta, muchas gracias

CONEXION A LA BD

```
$usuario = "root";
$password = "";
$servidor = "localhost";
$basededatos = "lista_o";
$conexion = mysqli_connect( $servidor, $usuario, $password ) or die ("No se ha podido conectar al servidor de Base de datos");
$db = mysqli_select_db( $conexion, $basededatos ) or die ( "Upps! Pues va a ser que no se ha podido conectar a la base de datos" );
```

Los datos de estos foreachs los saco de otra website

```
foreach($match[1] as $urls)
{
      foreach($buscamea[1] as $tengoas)
      {
          foreach($titulos[1] as $titulo)
            {
              //AQUI MUESTRAN TODOS LOS TITULOS
              echo "<p>".$titulo."</p>";
            }
          foreach($listas[1] as $lista)
            {
              echo $lista;
            }
          foreach($descripciones[1] as $descripcion)
          {
            echo "<p>".$descripcion."</p>";
          }
      }
}
$insertar = mysqli_query($conexion, "INSERT INTO backup (nombre, desc_corta, desc_larga) VALUES
('$titulo', '$lista', '$descripcion')");
   if (!$insertar) {
 die("Fallo al guardar los datos:" . mysqli_error($conexion));
}
else {
 echo "<center><h1>subido con exito</h1></center>";
}
 mysqli_close( $conexion );
```

ASD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin terminar de entender muy bien que es lo que quieres hacer y viendo el codigo, quizas en este caso lo mas facil seria utlizar un unico for o foreach en lugar de ese cumulo de foreach,por otro lado si ejecutas la consulta despues de los foreach solo esta guardando los ultimos valores de los bucles.

Ejemplo con for:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO backup (nombre, desc_corta, desc_larga) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conexion , $sql)) {

    $count = count($titulos[1]);
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
        /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss", $titulos[1][$i], $listas[1][$i], $descripciones[1][$i]);

        /* ejecutar la consulta */
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        /* Mostrar */
        echo "<p>".$titulos[1][$i]."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$listas[1][$i]."</p>";
        echo "<p>".$descripciones[1][$i]."</p>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Resolviste mi pregunta y absolviste muchas de mis dudas, muchas gracias por entender lo confuso que estaba.

Comment: Aclaro para el que le sirva esto en: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss",
El "SSS" corresponde a strings.
///////////////
i  la variable correspondiente es de tipo entero
d  la variable correspondiente es de tipo double
s  la variable correspondiente es de tipo string
b  la variable correspondiente es un blob y se envía en paquetes

Comment: Yo usaría transacciones en este caso dado que quiere hacer 40 inserciones. ¿Y si alguna falla, cómo se controla luego lo que falta o no por insertar? Para manejo masivo de datos ¡transacciones!  o corres el riesgo de tener datos inconsistentes, de *creer*  que insertaste algo que no se insertó. De romperte la cabeza si luego te toca verificar lo que falta por insertar, etc. Y... en vez de 40  `execute` construir una sola cadena de inserción y ejecutar de una vez. Si fuera con PDO esto sería una *pasada*, preparas la consulta y le pasas todos los datos en un array en el `execute`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano sería ud tan amable de pasarme un ejemplo sobre esto? recien ando aprendiendo php, llevo 3 semanas recien, si no puede no hay problema, muchas gracias.